# Open Text file and check if it has been edited

Tags: excel, vba

I have VBA code for opening a text file and writing the lines into a sheet.

I now want to add a message box that would indicate if this file has been edited or not.

My code for opening the file is as follows:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() ' OPEN THE HISTORY FILE AND IMPORT INTO THE FULL HISTORY FILE SHEET
    
    Dim Wsheet As Worksheet, WRange As Range
    
    Set Wsheet = Sheets("Full History File")
    Set WRange = Wsheet.Range("A1")
    
        If IsEmpty(WRange.Value) = False Then
            
            EmptyCheck
            UserForm_Activate
            ImportHistoryFile
    
        Else
    
            ImportHistoryFile
    
        End If
     
End Sub
```

Then:

```
 Sub ImportHistoryFile()
    
    Dim Fname As Variant, Text As String, Wsheet As Worksheet, WRange As Range, Cell As Integer
    
    Dim openPos As Integer
    Dim closePos As Integer
        
    Set Wsheet = Sheets("Full History File")
    Set WRange = Wsheet.Range("A1")
    
        Fname = Application.GetOpenFilename("History Files (*.txt), *.txt") 'OPEN THE FILE EXPLORER TO SELECT THE HISTORY FILE
    
        If Fname = False Then
    
            Exit Sub
    
        Else
    
            Open Fname For Input As #1
    
            Cell = 0
                Do Until EOF(1)
                    Line Input #1, Text
                    WRange.Offset(Cell, 0) = Text
                    Cell = Cell + 1
                Loop
            Close #1
        
            MsgBox "History file successfully opened " & Dir(Fname)
    
            openPos = InStr(1, Dir(Fname), "-") + 1
            closePos = InStr(openPos, Dir(Fname), ".")
    
            Frame1.Visible = True
            Frame1.Caption = Mid(Dir(Fname), openPos, closePos - openPos) & " History File Information and Summary"
            CommandButton2.Visible = True
            Label3.Visible = True
            Label3.Caption = Dir(Fname)
    
        End If
    
    End Sub
```

Any help on verifying the file integity when importing would be reatly appreciated.

Comment: How would you know if the file has been edited?

Comment: Thats exactly what I am trying to determine.

Comment: @HendrikSidaway Then you have to check hash value of that file.

Comment: Another way: Check if the created date and the modified are same or not. If it is not same then the file was edited.

Comment: Any idea how I would do that and what do I compare it to to verify it hasn't been edited?

Comment: Hi All, I found the value to compare to, but dont know how the value was created in the file: 4B98. Any ideas how I would determine this value and compare it to what is written in the file?